# How to load ocr-a font in r markdown with bookdown::pdf_document2 to change title font?

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex

I am trying to change the font for the title of my pdf document in rmarkdown to ocr-a. I have tried `tinytex::tlmgr_install("ocr")` but only received error messages:

```
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/<user>/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/<user>/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.
tlmgr update --self
fmtutil [ERROR]: format directory not writable: /var/lib/texmf/web2c
tlmgr install ocr
```

I have tried creating a `home/<user>/textmf` folder and copying `ocra.mf, ocra.afm, ocra10.mf, ocra.pfb, ocra.ttf, ocra12.mf, ocra17.mf` font files to the directory but this hasn't worked.

Also tried:

```
title: "My Title"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
header-includes:
- \usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr}
- \usepackage{titling}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\large\ocrfamily}
```

In yaml header and I get messages:
`! Font OT1/ocra/m/n/12=ocr12 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

I have tried placing the above files in

```
/home/<user>/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/public/ocr
```

again to no benefit.

Comment: Does it work if you run `tlmgr init-usertree` first?

Comment: `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: user mode database already set up in
tlmgr:   /home/michael/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
tlmgr: not overwriting it.` if I do that in terminal as sudo.

Comment: Try to install `xzdec` with your debian package manager thing. if this does not help, follow the instructions and report to the mailinglist mentioned in the error message

Comment: Your comment resolved the xzdec issue however, it turns out that there is a ```tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2022)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
tlmgr update --self
fmtutil [ERROR]: format directory not writable: /var/lib/texmf/web2c
tlmgr install ocr``` issue. So I am updating texlive ...

Comment: If you are anyway installing texlive, it might be worth considering a complete vanilla install from https://tug.org/texlive/ instead of tinytex. This would avoid missing packages in the future because it will install all the packages.

Comment: Did that. Now tinytex cannot find texlive, even after reinstall ```sigh```

Comment: How are you using rmarkdown? From rstudio?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244717/discussion-between-fatm-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).